# SQL very simple nested query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a nested query. I have a table named clicks with several columns among which are Datestamp, Keyword, Product_Title. The inner query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT(k.Keyword) 
FROM clicks k 
WHERE (k.Keyword LIKE '%word1%' AND k.Product_Title LIKE '%word2%');
```

Now I want to query for a bunch of rows such that the Keyword is one of the Keywords returned in the above query. I do the following:

```
SELECT c.Datestamp,c.Keyword,c.Product_Title 
FROM clicks c 
WHERE c.Keyword IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT(k.Keyword) 
    FROM clicks k 
    WHERE (k.Keyword LIKE '%word1%' AND k.Product_Title LIKE '%word2%')
);
```

Simple as this might seem, it doesn't work. The query just hangs there. No error message, no feedback whatsoever, just hangs there. I don't have that many rows, about 300k, so I'm sure the issue isn't the table being too big.

Suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that you want an `AND` in your `WHERE`-Condition? The way you posted it here, there won't ever be a result because it's always false.

Comment: `distinct` is ***not*** a function

Comment: @schlonzo what? Yes there is. Keyword, Product_Title

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Like I said, the inner query runs perfectly.

Comment: I just wanted to point that out, because your usage of parentheses around the column indicates that you _might_ have misunderstood how `distinct` works. `distinct (col1), col2` is the same as `distinct col1, col2` or `distinct (col1, col2)`. `distinct` always operates on all columns in the select list and the parentheses will not change that behaviour.

Comment: @oneloop Sorry, my fault. Misunderstood the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your subquery run fast? Make sure you have an index on `Keyword` field it will make your query faster. Also try to use JOIN:

```
SELECT c.Datestamp,c.Keyword,c.Product_Title 
FROM clicks c 
JOIN
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT(k.Keyword) 
      FROM clicks k 
     WHERE (k.Keyword LIKE '%word1%') AND (k.Product_Title LIKE '%word2%')
  )  d on c.Keyword=d.Keyword
```

See [MySQL Subquery Limitations](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/10/25/mysql-limitations-part-3-subqueries/) for more info.

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks. I would still like to understand why my query doesn't. If no one can explain it, then I will mark this answer as correct.
Yes, the subquery runs fast, less than half a second.

Comment: @oneloop: [MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/10/25/mysql-limitations-part-3-subqueries/)

Comment: Ok, so I guess it doesn't really hang, it's just really really slow. I'm marking it as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct c.Keyword, c.Datestamp, c.Product_Title FROM clicks c
where c.Keyword   LIKE '%word1%' AND c.Product_Title LIKE '%word2%'
```

Comment: No, that's not the same.